Pros & cons of Sallen-Key vs. double RC cascaded stages low pass filter topologies
Here are two possible topologies to implement an active non inverting second order low pass filter, namely Sallen-Key and two cascaded RC stages.


Both circuits have the same transfer function:
$$H(j\omega) = \frac{V_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}} = \frac{H0}{1 - \left(\omega / \omega_n\right)^2 - j  2\zeta\left(\omega / \omega_n\right)}$$
Theoretically they are equivalent, but I am sure that there are also practical considerations that may render one topology more convenient than the other depending on the application.
What are the pros/cons of each topology?
I have envisaged that in the Sallen-Key topology, the feedback introduced by \$C_1\$ may reduce the phase margin so it may tend to oscillate specially when DC gain \$1+R_4/R_3\$ increases. In the two cascaded \$RC\$ stage topology, conversely, \$C_1\$ does not affect op amp tendency to oscillate.

Homework?  How well can you realize a filter with a damping ration of $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ with a Sallen-Key?  How well can you do that with two cascaded RC stages?

Are you sure both have the same transfer function? The Sallen-Key implements a quadratic with conjugate complex poles, and the RCs each implement a single real pole.

@TimWescott Could you pls be more explicit? I couldn't catch your point. Many thanks.

@SteKulov Depending on component values, you get a couple of single real poles or a couple of complex conjugate poles. I am interested in this last case. Anyway the transfer function is definitively the same for both.

This sounds like homework.  We're not going to do your homework for you.  We will ask leading questions, like the one that I did.  Leading questions whose answers will help you be a better engineer.  Specifically -- please show us the R and C values needed to get a complex pole pair out of a cascaded RC filter.  We're interested.

@Guille  I'm also interested in the last case.  Can you show me how it can be done?

In short:

Both circuits provide a second-order lowpass function with gain

First circuit (Sallen-Key):



Advantage: Depending on the closed-loop gain of the opamp you can realize both - low-Q functions (2 real poles) or high-Q functions (a complex pole-pair).

Disadvantage: High-frequency attenuation will be limited because for rising frequencies an increasing portion of the input signal will be coupled directly via C1 to the output (non-zero opamp output impedance, rising with frequency).


EDIT: An additional disadvantage of the Sallen-Key topology results from the positive feedback (which allows the mentioned Q-enhancement): Positive feedback will always increase the sensitivity of the transfer function to component tolerances. In particular, the sensitivity to the gain determining resistors R3 and R4 is critical. For this reason, the unity-gain configuration (short between opamps output and the invering input) is often preferred.

Second (passive) circuit:

Advantage: Better attenuation for very high frequencies (see Sallen-Key disadvantage).


EDIT: It was shown elsewhere that such a passive ladder topolgy has the smallest sensitivity to componenet tolerances -if compared with all other active filter circuits.

Disadvantage: Only real poles are possible (bad transition from passband to stop-band). No higher-Q transfer functions are possible (Bessel, Butterworth, Chebyshev,..)



Both circuits have the same transfer function:
$$H(j\omega) = \frac{V_\text{out}}{V_\text{in}} = \frac{H0}{1 - \left(\omega / \omega_n\right)^2 - j\zeta\left(\omega / \omega_n\right)}$$

That is untrue. Well, maybe it is better to say it can lead to misunderstandings.
In the Sallen-Key design \$\zeta\$ is a variable whereas in the simple cascaded RC design it does not have this feature i.e. \$\zeta\$ is always unity when the two RC time constants are the same. If the two RC time constants are not the same then the equivalent value of \$\zeta\$ rises above unity i.e. it becomes a "sloppier" filter.
This is fundamentally different to the Sallen-Key design. It can readily produce values of \$\zeta\$ much smaller than unity and produce (for example), a Butterworth response where the pass-band spectrum is maximally flat. This cannot be achieved with cascaded RC sections (even if they are buffered to prevent unwanted loading of the 2nd stage on the first stage).
So, in a Sallen-Key design, \$\zeta\$ can extensively modify the shape of the filter in the resonance area as shown in these diagrams from my basic website: -


If you derive the transfer function of two unbuffered cascaded RC stages you get this: -
$$\dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + s\left(\frac{C_1R_1+C_2R_2}{C_1R_1C_2R_2}\right)+\omega_n^2}$$
Where \$\omega_n^2\$ equals \$\frac{1}{C_1R_1C_2R_2}\$
This is in the standard form for a 2nd order low-pass filter where the "s" coefficient equals: -
$$\frac{C_1R_1+C_2R_2}{C_1R_1C_2R_2} = 2\zeta\omega_n$$
If you drill down you will find that \$2\zeta\$ equals this: -
$$2\zeta = \sqrt{\frac{C_1R_1}{C_2R_2}} + \sqrt{\frac{C_2R_2}{C_1R_1}}$$
Then, if you analysed the above formula. you will find that the lowest value \$\zeta\$ can become is when both CR time constants are identical in value and, the result is that \$2\zeta = 2\$ or, \$\zeta = 1\$.

For the passive circuit, the parameter ζ even can assume values below unity.

@LvW I know what you mean but, the maths does not include a zeta term for two cascaded low-pass filters (if they were connected with a buffer in between or numerically so different in terms of impedance that the 2nd one didn't load the first one). Of course, when loading does take place the filter can have a much poorer response and, that response could be modelled by a Sallen-Key filter with zeta greater than unity.

@ Andy aka - sorry for my mistake.  Normally, I think in terms of quality factor Q. Therefore, speaking about damping I should say: The damping factor even can be larger than unity (two real poles). With other words - the Q-factor for a passive 2nd-order lowpass can even be smaller than 0.5.

Just checking my understanding here. Is it safe to think of it like this?: If zeta equals 1 then it corresponds to two real poles right on top of each other. If you increase zeta above 1 it’s like you’re splitting the two poles horizontally but they’re still on the real axis. And decreasing zeta below 1 splits the two poles vertically so they become complex conjugates.

@SteKulov you got it right.

Your statement that the two have the same transfer function is false. This can be seen by inspection of their simplified equivalents:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here \$K=1+\frac{R_4}{R_3}\$ is gain of the op-amp section, so that:
$$ V_X = K \times V_P $$
$$ V_Y = K \times V_Q $$
The Sallen-Key design (bottom) applies potential \$K\times V_Q\$ to the bottom end of C1, while the other applies 0V, a difference which would be very evident in their respective transfer functions:
$$ X(s) = \frac{K}{1+s(C_2R_2+C_2R_1+C_1R_1)+s^2(C_1R_1\cdot C_2R_2)} $$
$$ Y(s) = \frac{K}{1 + s \left( C_2 R_2 + C_2R_1 + C_1 R_1 (1 - K) \right) + s^2(C_1 R_1 \cdot C_2 R_2) } $$
They do not have the same transfer functions, but the difference is subtle; only the coefficient of \$s\$ in the denominator changes, with its \$C_1R_1\$ term being scaled by \$1-K\$.
For the two functions to be equal, \$Y(s)=X(s)\$, we require coefficients of \$s\$ and \$s^2\$ in each to be equal:
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_{X1}R_{X1} &= C_{Y1}R_{Y1} \\ \\
C_{X2}R_{X2}+C_{X2}R_{X1}+C_{X1}R_{X1} &= C_{Y2}R_{Y2}+C_{Y2}R_{Y1}+C_{Y1}R_{Y1}(1-K) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
You have some flexibility with the cascaded RC design, in that the factor \$K\$ is arbitrary, not changing the position of poles in any way. You can set its \$K\$ to whatever you want in your endeavour to make \$X(s)=Y(s)\$. However, \$K\$ for the Sallen-Key design is constrained to \$K\ge 1\$, and changing it does alter poles.
I haven't examined in detail the feasibility of obtaining \$X(s)=Y(s)\$, but I think there are severe constraints on candidate values of resistance, capacitance and gain \$K\$ that can achieve such equality. There are transfer functions realisable with cascaded RC filters that Sallen-Key cannot achieve, and Sallen-Key can implement transfer functions that cascaded RC filters cannot. Consequently, the question of pros and cons seems somewhat moot, superseded by a consideration what one can do that the other cannot and vice-versa.
Having said that, there are differences not related to the transfer function that deserve mentioning. The first is that the cascaded RC design doesn't (technically) need an amplifier. As long as the following stage doesn't load node P, it can have whatever features you desire; it could be a power stage, or an audio compressor, or another low-pass filter for a third pole. The Sallen-Key design mandates an op-amp, and precludes you from shoe-horning in additional roles for it.
The second difference that comes to mind is that the output of the op-amp in the Sallen-Key design is loaded by its own feedback. This feedback path is a sink/source of current that the op-amp output must provide, while also "driving" whatever comes next. While this isn't usually considered in academic material describing Sallen-Key, in practical designs you must ensure that the op-amp can sink and source both feedback and load current simultaneously. The amplifier following a cascaded RC filter has no such feedback load to worry about.

I am afraid you did misunderstand me. My assertion is not false: both topologies have a second order low pass transfer function that is the one indicated in my question (pls notice I added a missing 2 factor in the denominator).
Now if you call tau_1=C1R1, tau2=C2R2, tau_x=C2*(R1+R2) then you can easily show that for Sallen-Key zeta=0.5*(tau_x/sqrt(tau1tau2)-R4/R3sqrt(tau1/tau2)) and for 2 cascaded RC zeta=0.5*(tau_x+tau1)/sqrt(tau1tau2). For both topologies wn=1/sqrt(tau1tau2).
(it follows in next comment)

(continued from previous comment)
So by choosing appropriately component values you can get exactly the same transfer function for both topologies. The problem is that zeta in the cascaded RC cannot have arbitrary small values (thanks to LvW and TimWescott for pointing it out), the minimum should be 1.5, which implies 2 simple real poles which in turn means low Q.
Conversly, Sallen-Key leave you more degrees of freedom to make zeta virtually as small as you want...

In the above comment it should say "should be 1" instead of "should be 1.5". Sorry for the mistake.

@Guille I understand that I didn't quite grok your question, sorry about that, so I rewrote most of my answer with some additional points that may be pertinent.

Ok, still, transfer functions are formally the same, that is what I meant.
